# Построить график по многомерному массиву по выбранным столбцам?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, matplotlib

Доброго времени суток!
Имеются следующие входные данные в csv:

```
like,comment,repost,date
20,0,0,1488313047
32,2,0,1495235606
18,1,0,1495205070
12,0,0,1495093752
...
```

Последний столбец - дата публикации записи в сообществе в epoch-формате.
Считываю их и записываю в многомерный массив.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с использованием методов matplotlib построить график на основании этих данных, если в качестве оси абсцисс необходимо использовать данные четвертого столбца, а в качестве оси ординат — первого?
Если да, то есть ли необходимость в преобразовании столбца с датами epoch в другой формат и как это сделать?
Если нет, то как построить график на основании массива, где будут только 2 столбца (если я изменю входные данные на

```
20,1488313047
32,1495235606
18,1495205070
12,1495093752 
...
```

) и опять же, нужно ли преобразовывать даты?

Comment: `нужно ли преобразовывать даты` - этот зависит от того что вы хотите видеть по оси `X` - реальные дату/время или число (`epoch`)...

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение с использованием модуля Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# parse ['like','date'] CSV columns 
df = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/file.csv', usecols=['like','date'])
# convert UNIX epoch to datetime
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, unit='s')
# plot ...
df.plot(x='date', y='like')

plt.show()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]